# Search for or simply search

Tags: prepositions

He had lost a ring in the sand and (a)/ I helped him *search for* it, (b)/ but it was like a look for a
needle in a haystack. (c)/ No error (d)

In book , it says to remove **for** in (b)??? But Why??

Comment: That sentence isn't good English; the idiomatic form would be "He had lost a ring in the sand and I helped him search for it, but it was like looking for a needle in a haystack."

Comment: What is the source (the book?)  Stuart's usage above is correct.  Removing "for" to form "...but it was like a look a needle in a haystack" is even worse.  Unless you've mis-copied from the textbook, now is the time to find a better textbook.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **search** can take a direct object that refers to the location of the search:

> I searched **the cluttered drawer** <sup>direct object</sup> for a pencil. It was like looking for a needle in a haystack.
>
> I searched the assemble-it-yourself furniture store for an exit.

Answer (score 0):

The book is not correct, unless it is referring to searching the sand. (Which is not how a native speaker would say it.)

What changes meaning is the word “**it**”. If the **for** is in the sentence then “**it**” would mean the ring, without “**for**” then **”it”** refers to the sand

I hope that isn’t too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Because the book is wrong.

The verb phrase "look for" is perfectly good English. What is wrong in b) is the use of "a". According to "the book", b) should read, "but it was like a look a needle in a haystack." Since "look" alone (not "look at" or "look for") in intransitive (has no subject) the phrase "a needle in a haystack" is simply floating by itself. It's made worse by not using the gerund form of "look". This makes the "look" a single, short-duration event. And that is hardly appropriate for a time-consuming task like searching through an entire haystack just to find a single, tiny, needle.